# Как вывести новый масив

Tags: java, массивы

Как вывести новый масив из елементов в блоке if?
Нужно вывести масив из отобраных объектов.

```
public class BookModel {

private Book[] books;

public BookModel() {
    books = DataSourceBooks.getArray();
}

public Book[] getBooks() {
    return books;
}


public Book[] getSpecificBook(String s) {
    Book[] newBooks;
    for (Book book : books) {
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(book.getAuthor()) ||
                s.equalsIgnoreCase(book.getPublisher())) {

        }
    }
    return newBooks;

}

public Book[] getSpecificBook(int year) {
    for (Book book : books) {
        if (book.getYear() >= year) {

        }
    }
    return
}

public Book[] sortShape() {
    Book[] newBook = Arrays.copyOf(books, books.length);
    Arrays.sort(newBook, new SortByPublisher());
    return newBook;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью стримов легко:

```
public Book[] getSpecificBook(String s) {        
    return Arrays.stream(books)
            .filter(s->s.equalsIgnoreCase(book.getAuthor()) || s.equalsIgnoreCase(book.getPublisher()))
            .toArray(Book[]::new);
}
```

это проще, как и проще переписать этот метод

```
public Book[] sortShape() {
    return Arrays.stream(books)
            .sorted(new SortByPublisher())
            .toArray(Book[]::new);
}
```

Можно и так (без стримов тоже жили)

```
public Book[] getSpecificBook(int year) {
    List<Book> booksList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Book book : books) {
        if (book.getYear() >= year) booksList.add(book);
    }
    return booksList.toArray(new Book[booksList.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Да это верно, спасибо большое, но хотелось бы знать есть ли способ с for each

Comment: @Semkov Stanislav да, можно , но не настолько лаконично. ответ дополнил